# How hide page if user not logged in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When a user, who is not logged, in enters to mysite.com/cabinet the view includes cabinet details.  How do I hide current page if a user is not logged in and redirect to home page. I used this code, but not working.

```
if (!is_user_logged_in() && is_page('cabinet') ) {
    wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.dev/page/' ); 
}
```

*cabinet - page-cabinet.php

Comment: use if and else condition block for manage the page redirect into template_redirect action hook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are getting "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" error if you using your code in the template file.

Try this:

```
function mh_check_loggedin_redirect()
{
    if( is_page( 'cabinet' ) && ! is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        die;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'mh_check_loggedin_redirect' );
```

Note: Add this code in the functions.php file

Comment: Great to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect by using `template_redirect` action hook

```
function my_page_template_redirect()
{
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && is_page(YOUR_PAGE_ID) ) {
    {
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.dev/page/' ); 
        die;
    }

   if(is_user_logged_in() && is_page(YOUR_PAGE_ID) ) {
   {
        wp_redirect( site_url() ); 
        die;
   }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```

***Note :** Replace `YOUR_PAGE_ID` with your page id.

For more help : [Click Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect)

Comment: Not working, when not logged user  enter address bar mysite.com/cabinet redirect not working.

Comment: use page id in is_page('YOUR_PAGE_ID'), Please see i have modified the answer

Comment: After adding this code to function.php server is error 505 an site down

Comment: have you replace  YOUR_PAGE_ID with your wordpress page id which are shown  in admin side during edit page .

Comment: Yes, i have replace page id but nothing, site down (

Comment: Thanks everyone, it's working, problems with my cache